# Button no longer clickable after giving it a border

Tags: html, css

This is super weird, when I add a border to my button it is no longer clickable visually, you can't see that its a button, you can't tell if it's just some text styled that way or a button is clicked, the button itself is still clickable, just no animation

(I tried removing the border and then it's clickable, like any other button)

```css
.button {
    background-color: hsl(71, 73%, 54%);
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: hsl(71, 73%, 54%) 1px solid;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 17px 145px;
    margin: 0 10% 11%;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: do you mean `border: hsl(71, 73%, 54%) 1px solid`?

Comment: Yes, that is the border which I mean.

Comment: The button is still clickable... you can see it by adding either `.button:active { background-color: hsl(71, 73%, 20%); }` or `onclick="console.log('button was clicked')"`

Comment: I just tested the clickability of a button by making some test javascript code. And the button works. Give more code, please. Perhaps the problem is in another part of the code.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't look like it is being clicked and that's all the code I'm using, I tried it in a new document, same thing. are buttons like that? when giving border they lose their animation when you click them?

Comment: @Yuniac You set the border color to the same color as the background. Of course it's not going to look like anything is happening.

Comment: I thought of that, and tried a different color before asking here, nothing changed.

Comment: you need to style the rule `.button:active` and/or `.button:focus` with diffrent border/background - and make it look like clicked - by yourself.

Comment: How do you test the clickability of a button? What should happen when you click?

Comment: I'm sorry if I couldn't explain it in a better way but here is a Codepen without the border, try to click on that button, and then hopefully you can know what I mean: https://codepen.io/Yuniac/pen/oNzROmg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:active` to determine what happens when the button is being clicked. For example, to darken the background while the button is active:

```css
.button {
    background-color: hsl(71, 73%, 54%);
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: hsl(71, 73%, 54%) 1px solid;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 17px 145px;
    margin: 0 10% 11%;
}

.button:active {
  background-color: hsl(71, 73%, 30%);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: Yeah the problem was with the active state but that is a creative way to get around it, thank you, Jacob, this will suffice for now!

Answer (score 2):

as I mentioned in the comment before - you need to style it yourself to make it look like clickable.
Example - here:

https://jsfiddle.net/46gwz0bx/

...just added these:

```
.button:hover {
  background-color: hsl(71, 73%, 46%);
}
  
.button:active {
  background-color: hsl(71, 73%, 24%);
  border-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Yep, I just didn't expect it to be that way, I did something similar after that, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your button is still clickable. just add a hover effect as well.

```
<style>
  .button {
    background-color: hsl(71deg 86% 55%);
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid hsl(71, 73%, 54%);
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 17px 145px;
    margin: 0 10% 11%;
  }

  .button:hover {
    background-color: hsl(71, 75%, 50%);
  }
</style>

<button class="button" id="click">Sign Up</button>
```

Maybe some other element or js code can affect the button. can we see the full code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I should have been more clear from the start but I have edited my post now to fully explain what I meant, and that is all my code.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about your question but your button is clickable.

```
<style>
  .button {
    background-color: hsl(71, 73%, 54%);
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid hsl(71, 73%, 54%);
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 17px 145px;
    margin: 0 10% 11%;
  }
</style>

<button class="button" id="click">Sign Up</button>

<script>
  let click = document.getElementById('click');
  click.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log(event.target)
  });
</script>
```

console.log() ==> Output

Comment: Sure, but I am concerned about the visual part, it doesn't look like it is being clicked, as you can see in the snippet.

Comment: If you want to look like it is being clicked add.      .button:active                 .button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}.   Something like this